# How to test for significant difference in multilevel data?

Tags: statistical-significance, multilevel-analysis, differences

I work with a multilevel data set like the one below.

```
Scenario  Group  individual  Measurement
1          1       1             555
2          1       2             525
..         ...     ...           ...
10         1       10            565
11         2       1             1250
12         2       2             1300
...        ...     ...           ...
20         2       10            1199
...        ...     ...           ...
2000       200     10            345
```

The groups are problems to be solved and the individuals are different configurations (i.e., different settings of parameter values) of a single algorithm. The measurements represent the performance value of running an algorithm with configuration *a* on problem *b*. Lower values are better.

In a second experiment all scenarios an run again, but now the algorithm has a slightly modified implementation that I expect to result in better performance measurements. So what I have is the following

```
Scenario  Group  individual  Measurement 1  Measurement 2
    1          1       1             555        515
    2          1       2             525        520
    ..         ...     ...           ...        ...
    10         1       10            565        555
    11         2       1             1250       1248
    12         2       2             1300       1296
    ...        ...     ...           ...        ...
    20         2       10            1199       1120
    ...        ...     ...           ...        ...
    2000       200     10            345        296
```

I would like to test whether the measurements between the two experiments significantly differ to indicate that the modification led to better performance results (i.e, lower values). So I'm not really interested in individual scenarios, but on average for the entire data set I would like to know whether measurement 2 is significantly better than measurement 1. What test could I use that takes into account the multilevel data structure?

Comment: I think you need to explain more about the context and what you want to test.

Comment: I elaborated on the context to hopefully make it more clear what I would like to test